# Use value from a column as paramater for json request and combine the table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using power query to load some json data in a table (matches). I want to use a specific part of that data (fixture_id) as a parameter for another json request in another query (predictions), and then combine that output in my main (matches) table. Anyone can point me in the right direction on how to do this ?

So here is my matches table:

[image]

And then in my fixtures table i can maybe i have:

```
apiKey = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiKey"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
fixtureID = "?",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://v2.api-football.com/predictions/" & fixtureID, [Headers=[#"X-RapidAPI-Key"=apiKey]])),
```

If i hardcode the fixtureID, i get this output:

[image]

But i want to calculate it dynamically, and then merge the output to the matches table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to turn your request into a function that accepts parameters. Put your request on a new blank query:

```
let
    fnGetData = (fixtureID as text) => 
       let
           apiKey = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiKey"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
           fixtureID = "?",
           Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://v2.api-football.com/predictions/" 
& fixtureID, [Headers=[#"X-RapidAPI-Key"=apiKey]]))
       in
           Source
in
    fnGetData
```

Rename it to fnGetData.

Then, go to your table and click on Add Column/Add Custom Function. Select fnGetData and the input parameter is your fixtureID column. This should make all the requests and you'll just have to expand the new column results.

Comment: perfect, that works !! learned something new thanks a lot